# Hadoop namenode always needs formatting why?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a single node hadoop 1.0.4 and it works fine (I can run map-reduce jobs). The problem I have is whenever I restart and execute start-dfs.sh namenode is not up and I have to do "hadoop namenode -format" and then start-dfs.sh and start-mapred.sh always.. which forces me to load my data every time. Can you hint on a possible solution or configuration issues I may have to check?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not overriding the hdfs configurations `dfs.name.dir` , `dfs.data.dir`, by default it points to /tmp directory which will be cleared when your machine restarts. You have to change this from /tmp to another location in your home directory by overriding these values in your hdfs-site.xml file located in your HADOOP configuration directory.

Do the following steps

Create a directory in your home directory for keeping namenode image & datanode blocks (Replace  with your login name)

```
mkdir /home/<USER>/pseudo/
```

Modify your hdfs-site.xml file in your HADOOP_CONF_DIR(hadoop configuration direcotry) as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:///home/<USER>/pseudo/dfs/name</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:///home/<USER>/pseudo/dfs/data</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Format your hdfs namenode & start using

Comment: i consulted the doc and solved it, difference from yours is i have no file:/// prefix and there is no need to mkdir. hadoop namenode -format would create the directories. thanks anyways.

Comment: Cool. file:/// is used to differentiate between file systems, it is file:/// in case of local , for hdfs it is hdfs:// .It's only a standard way of doing, will work without using it also.